# How do you call the person working in the local government office?

Tags: word-request

If you go to the local government office for some requests, you talk with a person working in the office. How do you call them? 
I know some words like a government official, civil servant, office staff, office clerk. I'm not sure how I should designate them.

For example, let's say I make a conversation with a friend.

> I went to a local government office and spoke with _____

What's a suitable word for the blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having worked in the British civil service myself, I can tell you that most grades dealing with members of the public are *officers* of some level, for example, the historical administrative grades were *administrative officers*, *executive officers*, *higher executive officers* etc. At local government level, many workers are still called "government officers" ([see example](https://nationalcareers.service.gov.uk/job-profiles/local-government-officer)). Sometimes they have a specific job title relating to the service they provide, but unless you knew what that was "officer" is a pretty generic term that covers most roles and would be understood.

So you might say:

> I went to a local government office and *spoke with an officer*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any reason you prefer 'spoke' than 'told'?

Comment: A lot of UK Government departments have dome away with the old AO - EO - HEO grades. My own grade is a letter of the alphabet.

Comment: @kevin012 yes, we don't say "told *with*". It is the past participle of "tell", so we would only use it in connection with a specific statement, eg "I told him what to do". You could say "spoke with" or "talked to".

Comment: Kevin - _Told with_ is not a valid expression for having a conversation. If you tell someone something, you give them a piece of information.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Noted, I've added in that those were historic titles. Local government workers are still called officers, I've added a supporting link. I currently work in the NHS, and while we ditched the Whitley Council pay scales some 15 years ago, many roles still contain the term "officer".

Comment: @Astralbee & Kate Thanks!! I got it now.